# How to join two tables using selfjoin in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have two tables like `A` and `B`. In these two tables, I have around 50 columns. But I want a query which matches records based on the columns in both the tables

**matched  columns in both tables**

```
deductor_tan,
  tax_amount_credit,
  tax_deposited,
  section_code based on recon_execution_id=20140103
```

i try  like

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM A cd,
  B cdr
WHERE cd.deductor_tan    = cdr.deductor_tan
AND cd.section_code      = cdr.section_code
AND cd.tax_amount_credit = cdr.tax_amount_credit
AND cd.recon_execution_id=cdr.recon_execution_id
and cd.recon_execution_id=20140103 
and cdr.recon_execution_id=20140103
```

Is this query correct or not, please let me know

Comment: Just execute this query and see it for yourself... And if the output is not expected, let us know the details

Comment: my query is corrected or not ?

Comment: corrections needed... remove the last condition (`and cdr.recon_execution_id=20140103 ` which is redundant. `Count (*)` should be replaced by `count (Column name)`

Comment: then how can i select on perticular recon_execution_id=20140103

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, but contains some redundant (extra, unnecessary) condition -

Following thing

```
AND cd.recon_execution_id=cdr.recon_execution_id
and cd.recon_execution_id=20140103 
and cdr.recon_execution_id=20140103
```

Can be written as,

```
AND cd.recon_execution_id=cdr.recon_execution_id
and cd.recon_execution_id=20140103
```

Also, the title of your question is little confusing as there is no "self join" in the query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Removed redundancy, explicit column name based count, ANSI syntax

```
SELECT count(cd.deductor_tan)
FROM A cd INNER JOIN B cdr
ON (cd.deductor_tan = cdr.deductor_tan
AND cd.section_code = cdr.section_code
AND cd.tax_amount_credit = cdr.tax_amount_credit
AND cd.recon_execution_id = cdr.recon_execution_id)
WHERE cd.recon_execution_id = 20140103 ;
```